# Broadcast forwarding using Linux router

Tags: routing

I have 3 VLANs connected by a Ubuntu box acting as a router. Unicast packets are properly routed (machines can ping across VLANs,  etc). I am now trying to get broadcast working. I want to be able to broadcast into another VLAN by sending to that VLANs broadcast address.

How do I get the broadcast to work?

Comment: OK and what is the question?

Comment: I guess broadcast doesn't cross to other vlan when he is broadcasting from one to another?

Comment: @PetterH Clarified question. I want to be able to broadcast and I cannot, so can I reconfigure my router to allow it?

Comment: What's your use case here? Typically you want broadcasts to be limited to a single L2 segment.

Comment: VLANs divide broadcast domains.  That is their purpose.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_domain

Comment: I want to maintain separate broadcast domains, I just wanted to be able to broadcast to the domain from a machine outside the domain by having a router act as a repeater. Is that not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can't forward broadcasts between two different networks ( that is why they are separate networks ).  Instead you need to set up a single IP network ( same network address and netmask ) and bridge the two parts.  Have a look at the `brctl` command from the bridge-utils package to configure a bridge interface and bind the nics to it.